# XOR of three values

Tags: language-agnostic, logic, boolean, xor, boolean-expression

What is the simplest way to do a three-way exclusive OR?

In other words, I have three values, and I want a statement that evaluates to true IFF only *one* of the three values is true.

So far, this is what I've come up with:

((a ^ b) && (a ^ c) && !(b && c)) || ((b ^ a) && (b ^ c) && !(a && c)) || ((c ^ a) && (c ^ b) && !(a && b))

Is there something simpler to do the same thing?

---

Here's the proof that the above accomplishes the task:

```
a = true; b = true; c = true
((a ^ b) && (a ^ c) && !(b && c)) || ((b ^ a) && (b ^ c) && !(a && c)) || ((c ^ a) && (c ^ b) && !(a && b))
=> false

a = true; b = true; c = false
((a ^ b) && (a ^ c) && !(b && c)) || ((b ^ a) && (b ^ c) && !(a && c)) || ((c ^ a) && (c ^ b) && !(a && b))
=> false

a = true; b = false; c = true
((a ^ b) && (a ^ c) && !(b && c)) || ((b ^ a) && (b ^ c) && !(a && c)) || ((c ^ a) && (c ^ b) && !(a && b))
=> false

a = true; b = false; c = false
((a ^ b) && (a ^ c) && !(b && c)) || ((b ^ a) && (b ^ c) && !(a && c)) || ((c ^ a) && (c ^ b) && !(a && b))
=> true

a = false; b = true; c = true
((a ^ b) && (a ^ c) && !(b && c)) || ((b ^ a) && (b ^ c) && !(a && c)) || ((c ^ a) && (c ^ b) && !(a && b))
=> false

a = false; b = true; c = false
((a ^ b) && (a ^ c) && !(b && c)) || ((b ^ a) && (b ^ c) && !(a && c)) || ((c ^ a) && (c ^ b) && !(a && b))
=> true

a = false; b = false; c = true
((a ^ b) && (a ^ c) && !(b && c)) || ((b ^ a) && (b ^ c) && !(a && c)) || ((c ^ a) && (c ^ b) && !(a && b))
=> true

a = false; b = false; c = false
((a ^ b) && (a ^ c) && !(b && c)) || ((b ^ a) && (b ^ c) && !(a && c)) || ((c ^ a) && (c ^ b) && !(a && b))
=> false
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For exactly three terms, you can use this expression:

```
(a ^ b ^ c) && !(a && b && c)
```

The first part is `true` iff one or three of the terms are `true`. The second part of the expression ensures that not all three are `true`.

Note that the above expression does *NOT* generalize to more terms. A more general solution is to actually *count* how many terms are `true`, so something like this:

```
int trueCount =
   (a ? 1 : 0) +
   (b ? 1 : 0) +
   (c ? 1 : 0) +
   ... // more terms as necessary 

return (trueCount == 1); // or some range check expression etc
```

Comment: Great, but the general solution does not short-circuit.

Comment: `a ? 1 : 0` can be simplified to `!!a`

Comment: @gg.kaspersky, only in JavaScript, C, and languages which have truthy/falsy tests via the `!` operator. For example, this wouldn't work in Java or C#.

Comment: @DrewNoakes, when I made the comment, I thought for some reason that the question was C specific. Indeed, certain syntax constructs are valid only in certain languages.

Answer (score 20):

```
bool result = (a?1:0)+(b?1:0)+(c?1:0) == 1;
```

Comment: I love it.  Very simple and understandable.

Comment: The simplest and must understandable when reading the code (well, I'd add few spaces)

Comment: In Haskell: `list_xor xs = sum ( map (\x -> if x then 1 else 0) xs ) == 1`

Answer (score 9):

`a^b^c` is only 1 if an uneven number of variables is 1 (two '1' would cancel each other out). So you just need to check for the case "all three are 1":

```
result = (a^b^c) && !(a&&b&&c)
```

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility:

```
a ? !b && !c : b ^ c
```

which happens to be 9 characters shorter than the accepted answer :)

Comment: Kinda glad this is not the accepted answer for readability reasons, but still, I had to upvote as shortness still has some kinky appeal to me. On university in C class, we had a contest in writing the shortest source code that generates a song similar to Heidis Kuken, and I was in TOP 5 in a contest.

Comment: @Vlasec I assume you know about [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), but if you didn't here you go.

Answer (score 3):

Better yet on Python:

```
result = (1 if a else 0)+(1 if b else 0)+(1 if c else 0) == 1
```

This can be used also on if statements!

It saved my day for CLI mutually exclusive arguments through Click (everyone hates click)

Comment: python converts bool to int, so `result = bool(a) + bool(b) + bool(c) == 1`

Comment: and if a, b and c are already booleans, you can simply say `result = a + b + c == 1`

Answer (score 2):

You could also try (in C):

`!!a + !!b + !!c == 1`

Comment: This is only valid in some languages [eg. javascript], and it's not a simplification. In a language which auto-converts boolean to number for `+`, if `a`, `b`, and `c` are already boolean, you also don't need the double negation `!!`: just `a+b+c===1` will be equivalent.

Comment: @blgt, my mistake, I should specify that I meant to be an answer for C language.

Comment: Using `!!` to guarantee a C true is `1` is actually pretty neat. A bit paranoid in the context of a boolean logic question though. If the rest of your code is well-written `a+b+c==1` should still be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general implementation that fails quickly when more than one `bool` is found to be `true`.

**Usage**:

```
XOR(a, b, c);
```

**Code**:

```
public static bool XOR(params bool[] bools)
{
    return bools.Where(b => b).AssertCount(1);
}

public static bool AssertCount<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int countToAssert)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var t in source)
    {
        if (++count > countToAssert) return false;
    }

    return count == countToAssert;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f= lambda{ |a| [false, false, true].permutation.to_a.uniq.include? a }
p f.call([false, true, false])
p f.call([false, true, true])
```

> $ true
>
> $ false

Because I can.

Answer (score 0):

In C:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>

bool array_xor(size_t array_size, bool[] array) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size && count < 2; i++) {
        if (array[i]) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count == 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works, nor is it simple.

Comment: Define "simple". It definitely works, as what it's doing is checking that exactly one element of the array is `true`. It works for an arbitrarily large array of booleans, not just 3 elements, and short circuits as soon as it finds a second element that is `true` (hence `&& count < 2`).

Answer (score 0):

result = (
BOOL_TO_INT( a)
+  BOOL_TO_INT ( b )
+  BOOL_TO_INT ( c )
) = 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).