# given a set of conditions, algorithmically determine only one can be True

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, validation, logic, conditional-statements

Given a set of two or more logical conditions, is it possible to algorithmically determine that exactly ONE of them will evaluate to TRUE? For example:

```
# this should pass, since for every X, only one condition is taken
cond 1: (X >= 1.0) 
cond 2: (X < 1.0)

# this should fail
cond 1: (X < 1.0)
cond 2: (X > 2.0)

# this should also fail, since X=1.0 would meet both conditions
cond 1: (X < 2.0)
cond 2: (X > 0.0)

# there may be more than one variable involved
cond 1: (X >= 1.0 && Y >= 0)
cond 2: (X < 1.0 && Y <= -1)
```

These conditions are generated from a domain specific language and used to determine the next execution path. i.e. users compose a condition for each option when the execution tree splits into multiple paths, and the condition that evaluates to true determines the path that is to be taken. For the simulation to be valid these should be only one possible path that can be taken for any given values.

At present, I evaluate these conditions at runtime and throw a tantrum if more than one (or none) of them are True.

I would like to be able to check errorneous conditions during the parse stage (domain language to compilable source code). Is it possible? How would one go about validating the conditions?

#### update

With regards to what can be included in the conditions, the scope is rather wide in practice. All these are possible conditions:

- `X >= Y && Y < Z`
- `X.within_radius(0.4)`
- `X IN some_array`
- `X * Y < Z`

#### final update

It does seem like a solution that covers all possible conditions is not possible (or at least, given my limited knowledge, not possible within the time allocated for the problem). Will revisit this some day, but for now accepting answer that brought me forward the furthest.

Comment: Are NULLs possible? The following may be a good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification

Comment: The last one should fail too shouldn't it? If X = 0 and Y = 0 then both conditions are false.

Comment: @Chris: You're right. Thanks. Will update.

Comment: @Lucero: (Unless I've misunderstood your question) NULLs are not possible outcomes of each condition. Each condition ought to evaluate to true of false.

Comment: Since the decisions are part of a decision tree, don't you have to include the parent conditions as well? For example, when you go down a path where `X > 2`, then two subsequent conditions `X < 1` and `X > 0` do *not* clash, but your static checking tool would probably report that they do.

Comment: @heinrich Sorry, bad use of terminology on my part. It's not quite a decision tree in the pure sense, but a point in the code execution where the conditions determine what gets called next

Comment: Yes; what I mean is that one condition might become superfluous because it is only checked when the previous code has already ruled it out. For example: `if (x > 2) { if (x < 1) { ... this branch is superfluous! } else {...} } else {...}`

Comment: @lsc, let's assume you're applying this to some SQL code. The variables `X` and `Y` could be NULL in that case. So, for the first sample, if `X=NULL`, is there one of the two conditions being true?

Comment: @Lucero, as far as I know, it is not possible for the variables to be NULL. With some of the variables being computed values, I suppose it is possible for them to be Inf/-Inf/NaN but in the case of NaN, the whole simulation is considered to be erroneous anyway so I'd discount that.

Comment: @heinrich, in the current application each condition is evaluated independently and its outcome is not influenced by any of the other conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I'll restate because it seems like the other answers are assuming a bunch of things which have since been confirmed:

If you can state your conditions (and the constraint that only one is true) in terms of [Presburger arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic), then you can write a decision procedure to verify that property statically.  This seems perfectly achievable from the examples above.

The "blunt instrument" approach is to basically interface with something like an automatic theorem prover or an SMT solver (where you would basically be trying to prove the negation of the statement "there exists some value x that satisfies constraint1 XOR constraint2").  I've programmatically interfaced with [CVC3](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/acsys/cvc3/) before, and found it pretty good to work with, but my understand is that it has been surpassed by other SMT solvers.

Anything else you do to solve this problem is probably going to end up approximating some implementation of the kinds of tools I've suggested, I think.  Depending on exactly how your constraints are specified, you might be able to get away with implementing some kind of decision procedure for something like [Presburger arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic).

Comment: Thanks Gian. I'll have a read and see that would fit the bill.

Comment: Agree with Gian. Also check the "code contract" concept, for example in Eiffel. A nice work on static verification of code contracts here: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/ , here: http://pexforfun.com/default.aspx?language=CSharp&sample=StringTrimSuffix and here: http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Peli/Static-Checking-with-Code-Contracts-for-NET/

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.  But if what you're really asking is whether it is possible given conditions made up of boolean logical combinations of inequalities on a finite set of independent integer variables with constants, then there's hope.  You can exhaustively check by permuting the variables with the constants that appear in your inequalities (and +1 and -1 of those constants), and verifying that the number of conditions that hold true is always 1.

Comment: That was what I thought, but I was hoping that the collective brain of S.O. can show me otherwise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find if only one condition is true (out of two or more possible conditions) it may be helpful to refer to this xor question on SO: [xor-of-three-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466452/xor-of-three-values).
Taking directly from its answer:

```
(a ^ b ^ c) && !(a && b && c)
```

In your case:

```
(cond 1 ^ cond 2 ^ cond 3) && !(cond 1 && cond 2 && cond 3)
```

There's also a general solution where you increment a count each time any condition is true, then check the count against 1 once all conditions have been tested.

Comment: Thanks gary. I already have a solution in place that does pretty much that. What I'm wondering now is if it is possible to check it statically and not at runtime. Values of a,b,c are not known in advance.

Comment: OK, I didn't understand the question at first. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are the building blocks of you conditions just

- an integer variable,
- a comparison operator out of (<, <=, >, >=),
- numbers (let's assume integers)?

And the final conditions are built from these using && and ||?

Can we assume all integer variables are independent?

Under these conditions, I would assume that it can be checked algorithmically. I would put all valid ranges per variable into a data structure, and check for intersections.

EDIT: As this does not seem to be the case, the best solution would probably be to group the different types of conditions so that the conditions in each group can be statically evaluated against each other. The type of conditions assumed by me from your first description would be just one of these groups.

Comment: (EDIT) I'm afraid the variables aren't limited to numbers and can contain function-like constructs that return True/False (e.g. x.within_radius(0.3) or (x IN somearray)). The conditions are NOT merge into a final condition, but rather, each condition is independent of each other and are assigned by users to a series of paths to determine the route of the simulation (hence the need for validation).