# T-SQL exactly 1 condition is true out of a set of conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What is the simplest way to express in T-SQL that only 1 and exactly 1 of a number of boolean conditions is true (needs to be usable in a CHECK constraint)?

`XOR` works for 2 conditons, eg `A XOR B` will insure that exactly 1 is set but it does not work for 3 conditions:

[image]

One solution would be to get some kind of collection out of them, filter on the conditions being true, perform and aggregate/sum and check that the result is equal to 1.

Comment: It may not be clear to people that the truth table you're showing is demonstrating *how XOR doesn't work for you*, rather than *what your expected result is*, which I've interpreted should be as shown except with `F` in the top line rather than `T`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I thought it was clear that the table shows how it works, not how it should work cause I mentioned this before: `but it does not work for 3 conditions:`

Answer (score 5):

I would structure your `CHECK` along the lines of:

```
CHECK (
    CASE WHEN <condition 1> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN <condition 2> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN <condition 3> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    = 1
)
```

It's slightly verbose but it is hopefully *readable* to see what your intention was. It also extends to other similar requirements more easily than XOR (e.g. "exactly 2 out of 5 conditions must be matched" can follow the same structure)

For SQL Server 2012 or later, you can be slight more concise with [`IIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx):

```
CHECK (
    IIF(<condition 1>,1,0) +
    IIF(<condition 2>,1,0) +
    IIF(<condition 3>,1,0)
    = 1
)
```

Comment: That would be a solution but still there is a lot of code duplication in it. See the update in my question.

Comment: @RăzvanPanda - I don't think the verbosity can be avoided. As you may be aware, SQL Server doesn't have a user-visible boolean data type - so you can't do something along the lines you propose since there's no way to represent intermediate results as *data*.

Comment: @RăzvanPanda - and also, obviously, this structure extends to cover other requirements more easily than an XOR based one (e.g. if you're requirement was "exactly 2 out of 5 conditions must be satisfied", you can trivially adjust the above to match that)

Comment: Any idea if it is possible to map over boolean conditions (since they can not be stored in a table literal)? See the answer I added for what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly taken from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466452/xor-of-three-values), a general formula for an exclusive OR between three variables can be written as:

```
(a ^ b ^ c) && !(a && b && c)
```

We can express this in SQL Server as:

```
(A XOR B XOR C) AND NOT (A AND B AND C)
```

Note that this only works for three variables, and does not generalize to higher numbers.  If you have more than three variables, you'll have to do more work.

Comment: Just wanted to post this :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all your conditions are represented as `BIT` columns, you can have a constraint with the format:

```sql
alter table [table_name] add constraint [constraint_name]
check ( ( a ^ b ^ c ) = 1 AND NOT ( a & b & c ) = 1 )
```

Doing this, you can also then use the same conditions in a case statement, like:

```sql
select a, b, c,
    case when (( a ^ b ^ c ) = 1 AND NOT ( a & b & c ) = 1) then 1
    else 0 end
    as true_or_false
from [table_name]
```

Putting this together, we can demo it with a script like:

```
create table #bits  (a bit, b bit, c bit)
create table #bits2  (a bit, b bit, c bit)

alter table #bits2 add constraint ck_xor
    check ( ( a ^ b ^ c ) = 1 AND NOT ( a & b & c ) = 1 )

insert into #bits
values
( 0, 0, 0 ), ( 0, 0, 1 ), ( 0, 1, 0 ), ( 0, 1, 1 ), ( 1, 0, 0 ), ( 1, 0, 1 ), ( 1, 1, 0 ), ( 1, 1, 1 )

select a, b, c,
    case when ( a ^ b ^ c ) = 1 AND NOT ( a & b & c ) = 1 then 1
    else 0 end
    as true_or_false
from #bits

insert into #bits2
select * from #bits
where ( a ^ b ^ c ) = 1 AND NOT ( a & b & c ) = 1 

-- the below line will fail because of the check constraint    
insert into #bits2 (a,b,c) values (1,1,0)

select * from #bits2

drop table #bits
drop table #bits2
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare three variable @a, @b , @c and it's bit type. Where 1 is true and 0 is false. Example with all possible of bit is here.

```
  declare @a bit, @b bit, @c bit;
set  @a=1; set @b=1;  set @c=1; select @a as a,@b as b,@c as c,  case when @a=@b then (case when @c=1 then 1 else 0 end) else (case when @c=0 then 1 else 0 end) end as xor;
set  @a=1; set @b=1;  set @c=0; select @a as a,@b as b,@c as c,  case when @a=@b then (case when @c=1 then 1 else 0 end) else (case when @c=0 then 1 else 0 end) end as xor;
set  @a=1; set @b=0;  set @c=0; select @a as a,@b as b,@c as c,  case when @a=@b then (case when @c=1 then 1 else 0 end) else (case when @c=0 then 1 else 0 end) end as xor;
set  @a=1; set @b=0;  set @c=0; select @a as a,@b as b,@c as c,  case when @a=@b then (case when @c=1 then 1 else 0 end) else (case when @c=0 then 1 else 0 end) end as xor;

set  @a=0; set @b=1;  set @c=0; select @a as a,@b as b,@c as c,  case when @a=@b then (case when @c=1 then 1 else 0 end) else (case when @c=0 then 1 else 0 end) end as xor;
set  @a=0; set @b=1;  set @c=0; select @a as a,@b as b,@c as c, case when @a=@b then (case when @c=1 then 1 else 0 end) else (case when @c=0 then 1 else 0 end) end as xor;
set  @a=0; set @b=0;  set @c=0; select @a as a,@b as b,@c as c, case when @a=@b then (case when @c=1 then 1 else 0 end) else (case when @c=0 then 1 else 0 end) end as xor;
set  @a=0; set @b=0;  set @c=0; select @a as a,@b as b,@c as c,  case when @a=@b then (case when @c=1 then 1 else 0 end) else (case when @c=0 then 1 else 0 end) end as xor;
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce even more from the code duplication and make it a bit more readable something like this could be used:

```
(SELECT SUM(ExpressionValue)
FROM
    (VALUES
        (CASE WHEN 42 = 42 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        (CASE WHEN 42 = 42 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        (CASE WHEN 42 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        (CASE WHEN 42 = 42 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    ) AS conditions(ExpressionValue))
=
1
```

Example usage:

```
DECLARE @say as VARCHAR(MAX) =
    CASE
        WHEN (
            (SELECT SUM(ExpressionValue)
            FROM
                (VALUES
                    (CASE WHEN 42 = 42 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
                    (CASE WHEN 42 = 42 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
                    (CASE WHEN 42 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
                    (CASE WHEN 42 = 42 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                ) AS conditions(ExpressionValue))
            =
            1
        ) THEN 'Only one set'
        ELSE 'Non only one set'
    END

PRINT @say
```

It could still be improved if it is somehow possible to elegantly just apply the case operation similar to a map.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tt table (i int, b1 bit, b2 bit, b3 bit);
insert into @tt values (1,0,0,0), (2,1,1,1), (3,1,0,0)
select i, b1, b2, b3 
from @tt 
where cast(b1 as tinyint) + cast(b2 as tinyint) + cast(b3 as tinyint) = 1
```