# XOR operation on three values

Tags: boolean, logical-operators, boolean-logic, xor

I have three boolean values. I need to return `false` if all three are `true` or if all three are `false`. I will return `true` in every other situation. Based on my research, in some specifications this is called a three-variable exclusive-or.

Edit: Some specifications claim a three variable XOR involves the only `true` result would come from a set where only one parameter is `true`. The XOR I am referring to here is of another specification where multiple values may be `true`, but not all.

- What's the fastest way to perform this operation? `a xor b xor c` doesn't work
- What's if it wasn't three but n parameters?

Here's the truth table for my desired operation (xor with three params).

```
A   B   C   -
T   T   T   F
T   T   F   T
T   F   T   T
T   F   F   T
F   T   T   T
F   T   F   T
F   F   T   T
F   F   F   F
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XOR of three values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466452/xor-of-three-values)

Comment: @subdeveloper Unfortunately not. Edited my question to explain further why. In that question he asks `I want a statement that evaluates to true IFF only one of the three values is true.` This is not the same as mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make an algorithm for that, you need to know how to use karnaugh map in three variable. See sample karnaugh map [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHj5N.jpg)

Ok. First, to make things easier replace T as **1** and F as **0** in your truth table.

At first glance, it is just an increasing 3-bit binary. So arranging it in an increasing way is a good idea. Take a look below.

```
A   B   C       F(A,B,C)
0   0   0       0
0   0   1       1
0   1   0       1
0   1   1       1
1   0   0       1
1   0   1       1
1   1   0       1
1   1   1       0
```

By using karnaugh-map, you will get a boolean expression below.
For the first expression we get **A'B** .

[image: see image 1]

For the second expression **AB'** .

[image: see image 2]

For the third expression **B'C** .

[image: see image 3]

For the fourth expression  **BC'** .

[image]

To simply understand karnaugh-map, if all **1's** are inside the straight sight towards the table of a variable then one term of expression will contain only that variable. But if **1's**  are outside the straight sight of that variable, then, it is a compliment of that variable.

```
F(A,B,C) = A'B + AB'+ B'C + BC'
```

but since

```
A XOR B = AB'+ A'B
B XOR C = BC'+ B'C
```

then our simplified form will be

```
F(A,B,C) = A XOR B + B XOR C
```

for pseudo code programming, it is equivalent to

```
result = (A XOR B) OR (B XOR C)
//other else
result = (A ^ B) | (B ^ C)
```

Comment: Wow, great read. Can you explain how you got from the 3 bit binary step to the `F(A,B,C) = A'B + AB'+ B'C` step?

Comment: Sorry i forgot BC' . It should be
F(A,B,C) = A'B + AB'+ B'C + BC'

Comment: Thanks. On this step: `A XOR B = AB'+ A'B`. The `+` represents `OR`?

Comment: @Hatefield yes you are correct. It is like multiplication is AND and addition is OR, but, they mean different way. This is used mostly in boolean expression analysis.

Answer (score 4):

Use this :

`(A XOR B) OR (B XOR C)`

Works for `n` inputs as well :

`(A XOR B) OR (B XOR C) OR ...(n XOR n+1)`

Comment: Thank you. I came upon this answer with a friend just minutes ago. Glad it's correct.

Comment: Glad you changed the accepted answer for good, Leandro's answer is more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Hear is my python implementation of it

```
def xor_three(a, b, c):
    return (a ^ b) or (b ^ c)

A = True
B = False
C = True

print(xor_three(A, B, C))
```

Answer (score 0):

If all 3 are true or all 3 are false, I think the best way is:

```
if (a AND b AND c) or (not a AND not b AND not c):
    # Do something
```

If you only want it returns true when one and only one of the values is true:

```
if int(a) + int(b) + int(c) == 1:
    # Do something
```

Many thanks!