# multiple !isset() with OR conditions in php

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

```
if(!isset($_GET['new_quiz']) || !isset($_GET['view_quiz']) || !isset($_GET['alter_quiz'])){
echo "No";
}
else{ echo "Yes"; }
```

When I go to *index.php?view_quiz*, it should give result as **Yes**, but it results as *No*. Why?

#### My Other Tries:

```
(!isset($_GET['new_quiz'] || $_GET['view_quiz'] || $_GET['alter_quiz']))
```

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression
>   (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in
>   C:\wamp\www\jainvidhya\subdomains\teacher\quiz.php on line 94

---

```
(!isset($_GET['new_quiz'],$_GET['view_quiz'],$_GET['alter_quiz']))
```

> NO

Comment: You have to use isset for each GET parameter. As the error message states you can't use the result of an operation as parameter for isset. Do isset(X) || isset(Y) instead of isset(X || Y)

Comment: @Fitzi That's was my first try

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I kinda missed that first part.

Comment: @Firtz: That's wrong, you can use `isset()` with more than 1 param. `ìsset(a,b)` is a short way for `isset(a) && isset(b)`. Or here: `!isset(a,b,c)` is a short form of `!isset(a) || !isset(b) || !isset(c)`.

Comment: Check index.php?view_quiz=something

Comment: @Wimm I did not say that you can't use isset with more than one parameter. I just stated that you can't use the result of an operation as parameter. OP also wasn't trying to check if all parameters are set but if a single one is. Therfore isset with multiple paramters isn't the right choice anyway. My username is Fitzi btw, not Firtz.

Answer (score 1):

You may find than inverting the logic makes the code easier to read, I also like to have a more positive idea of conditions as it can read easier (rather than several nots means no).

So this says if anyone of the items `isset()` then the answer is `Yes`...

```
if(isset($_GET['new_quiz']) || isset($_GET['view_quiz']) || isset($_GET['alter_quiz'])){
    echo "Yes";
}
else{ echo "No"; }
```

Note that I've changed the `Yes` and `No` branches of the `if` around.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for

```
if(!isset($_GET['new_quiz']) && !isset($_GET['view_quiz']) && !isset($_GET['alter_quiz'])){
    echo "No";
}
else {
    echo "Yes";
}
```

which will print *Yes* if none of new_quiz, view_quiz and alter_quiz are present in the URL. If this is not your desired outcome, please elaborate on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@paran you need to set a value for `view_quiz=yes` for example

```
if(!isset($_GET['new_quiz']) || !isset($_GET['view_quiz']) || !isset($_GET['alter_quiz'])){
echo "No";
}
else{ echo "Yes"; }
```

and the url

```
index.php?new_quiz=yes
index.php?view_quiz=yes
index.php?alter_quiz=yes
```

All Will return true

Answer (score 0):

`isset()`allows multiple params. If at least 1 param does not exist (or is NULL), isset() returns `false`. If all params exist, isset() return `true`.

So try this:

```
if( !isset( $_GET['new_quiz'], $_GET['view_quiz'], $_GET['alter_quiz']) ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to answer your question:

> When I go to index.php?view_quiz, it should give result as Yes, but it results as No. Why?

This is becaue this

```
if(!isset($_GET['new_quiz']) || !isset($_GET['view_quiz']) || !isset($_GET['alter_quiz'])){
```

checks if either one of your parameter is not set, which will always be the case as long as you are not setting all three parameter simultaneously like this:

> index.php?alter_quiz&view_quiz&new_quiz

As @nigel-ren stated, you may wan't to change that logic to

```
if(isset($_GET['new_quiz']) || isset($_GET['view_quiz']) || isset($_GET['alter_quiz'])){
    echo 'Yes';
```

which checks if **at least** one parameter is set.

---

If you wan't to check if there is **only one** of the three parameters set, you would have to work with XOR (which is slightly more complicated)

```
$a = isset($_GET['new_quiz']);
$b = isset($_GET['view_quiz']);
$c = isset($_GET['alter_quiz']);

if( ($a xor $b xor $c) && !($a && $b && $c) ){
    echo 'Yes';
```

(based on this answer: [XOR of three values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466452/xor-of-three-values))

which would return true if one and only one of the three parameters is set.

---

But - and this is just an assumption, please correct me if I'm wrong - I think what you are trying to achieve are three different pages (one for creating a quiz, one for viewing it and one for editing it). Therefore, you will likely run into a problem with your current setup. For example: What would happen if a user calls the page with multiple parameters, like

> index.php?alter_quiz&view_quiz

Would you show both pages? Would you ignore one parameter? I would recommend to work with a single parameter to avoid this problem in the first place. For example  `site` which can take the values `alter_quiz`, `view_quiz` or `new_quiz`. E.g.:

> index.php?site=alter_quiz

Then you can work like this:

```
// check if site is set before getting its value
$site = array_key_exists( 'site', $_GET ) ? $_GET['site'] : NULL;

// if it's not set e.g. index.php without parameters is called
if( is_null($site) ){
    // show the start page or something
}else{

    $allowed_sites = ['new_quiz', 'view_quiz', 'alter_quiz'];

    // never trust user input, check if
    // site is an allowed value
    if( !in_array($site, $allowed_sites, true) ){
        die('404 - This site is no available');
    }

    // here you can do whatever your site should do
    // e.g. include another php script which contains
    // your site
    include('path/to/your/site-' . $site . '.php');

    // or echo yes
    echo 'Yes';

}
```