# How to return True if only one variable of three is True in BASH?

Tags: bash, if-statement, scripting

How to return True if only one variable of three is True in BASH?

I have three boolean variables:

```
a|b|c|
1 1 1 False
1 1 0 False
1 0 1 False
1 0 0 True
0 1 1 False
0 1 0 True
0 0 1 True
0 0 0 False
```

I need a logical expression that returt true only if one variable is true.
I try with

```
if  [[ ( $a == 1 || $b == 1 || $c == 1 ) && ( $a == 1  &&  $b == 1  &&  $c == 1 ) ]];  then
  return True
fi
```

Thank you

Comment: Some language-agnostic solutions are shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3466452/2088135

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just sum the values and check whether the result equals 1.

Here, I'm using an arithmetic expression to sum the numbers and check the equality.

```
#! /bin/bash
for a in 0 1 ; do
    for b in 0 1 ; do
        for c in 0 1 ; do
            printf '%s ' $a $b $c
            (( 1 == a + b + c )) && echo True || echo False
        done
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the logic which i collected 
(a^b^c) &  ~(a&b&c)

xor all values and remove the case where all values of abc are true 
truth table

a b c      f = a^b^c     g = ~(a&b&c)     h = f&g

0 0 0         0            1        0

0 0 1         1            1        1

0 1 0         1            1        1

0 1 1         0            1        0

1 0 0         1            1        1

1 0 1         0            1        0

1 1 0         0            1        0

1 1 1         1            0        0

here f is the xor of a b and c and g is the negation of a&b&c
the output produces only when one value is true

Have a nice day